# How to disable a JButton for certain period of time?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would like to disable a `JButton` for about 10 seconds. Is there way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Do you need "to disable a `JButton` for about 10 seconds," or do you really need to disable a `JButton` and re-enable it after some other event?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But that leaves the button in an enabled state, which might be confusing to the user, however, if that meets the ops needs, who am I to say ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: when I [tested it](http://pastebin.com/NP4W8Lny), it seems to disable the button just fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ahh, but you're using an `Action`, yes this approach would be the best!  I thought you meant putting some code into the `ActionListener` to stop responding to the event ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yep, I'm using Action just as I stated in my original comment. This way you could disable any component that used the same Action, be it a button or a menu item.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Swing `Timer`, when triggered, it notifies the registered listener within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI from.

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

First read the answer from `@MadProgrammer` and go through the links provided there. If you still need a working example based on those suggestions, following is one.

**why the solution is better than few solutions presented**

It's because it uses a `javax.swing.Timer` to enable the button that enables GUI related tasks to be automatically executed on the event-dispatch thread (EDT). This saves the swing application from being intermixed with non EDT operations.

Please try the following example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SwingDemo extends JPanel {
    private final JButton button;
    private final Timer stopwatch;
    private final int SEC = 10;

    public SwingDemo() {
        button = new JButton("Click me to disable for " + SEC + " secs");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton toDisable = (JButton) e.getSource();
                toDisable.setEnabled(false);
                stopwatch.start();
            }
        });
        add(button);
        stopwatch = new Timer(SEC * 1000, new MyTimerListener(button));
        stopwatch.setRepeats(false);
    }

    static class MyTimerListener implements ActionListener {
        JComponent target;

        public MyTimerListener(JComponent target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            target.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame myApp = new JFrame();
        myApp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myApp.setContentPane(new SwingDemo());
        myApp.pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                myApp.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Please try the following example*" Why should they?  Can you explain why your solution is better than any of the other solutions presented?  The internet is full of "code walls" why should the OP trust yours? (FYI: You can setup a single run (non-repeating) time, so you don't need to manually stop it ;)) (ps, Yes I know why it's better, but I have the experience to see it ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for the feedback. I have edited the solution to make the timer non repeatable. As for why the solution is better than few solutions presented, is because it uses a `javax.swing.Timer` that enables GUI related tasks to be  automatically executed on the event-dispatch thread (EDT). This saves the swing application from being intermixed with non EDT operations.

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the OP, I agree, but as you can see, there are at least two other answers which the OP shouldn't use, why should they trust your solution. Add those comments to the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread`, `Task` or the simpler `Timer` class.

Comment: No, no, would need more info. Swing is not thread safe and there are better, safer ways to do it

Comment: Well of course Swing is not Thread-safe, but doesn't mean that you cannot use Threads! You can use a Thread to wait for 10 seconds and then use a Thread-safe call (SwingUtilities.invokeLater for example) to disable the Button. Waiting 10 seconds can be concurrent with Swing event-loop.

Comment: But, as I said, in this case, there is a simpler solution available ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can use Thread.sleep(time in mil seconds)

ex:
Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep for 10 seconds

```
JButton button = new JButton("Test");

    try {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        button.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it must be in a separate thread or it will make all the GUI hang for 10 seconds.

you can post more details about the code and i can help

Comment: Note: Swing is NOT thread safe, modifications to the UI MUST be executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This is violating two basic rules of Swing, DON'T block the Event Dispatching and DON'T update the UI from outside the Event Dispatching Thread (because you can't do one without doing the other based on your example)